# I'm trying to follow a tutorial in youtube but i don't have a bolt mesh . What should i do?

Tags: modeling

The tutorial is in this link: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryJ_xG3WeLw)

In minute 9:46 he is adding a bolt: Add > Mesh > Bolt
But i don't have any bolt mesh in the menu or sub menus of Add > Mesh

I saw someone else added comment about it but not one gave him answer.

Comment: I think you might have to enable an addon!! Maybe the tutorial mentions about the addon somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the Add-on "Bolt Factory" in the user preferences. 
[image]